# Function to display image in a div different from thumbnail with mouse on over

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an array of images of items for sale.
I display the images in a grid (for testing purposes, 5 rows and 6 columns).
To the side of the grid is a blank space, in which I want to display a large image corresponding to the small image in the grid on mouseover, so as the user goes through the display, the large image will change.

For the first row and column, the code looks like this:

```
<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" alt="" src="images/rings/small/1.jpg" />
```

My question is this: how do I display the corresponding large image in the blank space? 
In other words, how should I code the function `DisplayLargeImage(large-image-1)`?

Comment: Any code you use would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First you should include an empty `<img>` tag to hold your large image and give it a unique ID like:

```
<img id="largeDisplay" src="" />
```

Then you need to code your DisplayLargeImage(image) function like this:

```
function DisplayLargeImage(imageSource) {
    document.getElementById('largeDisplay').src = imageSource;
}
```

And dont forget to add the onclick function for each image in your grid

Comment: you didnt provide the code so i gave you the most simple solution. but your code can be optimized much more. also you should add some code to select the first image in your grid for "largeDisplay" by default

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I used the function :
<script type="text/javascript">
     function DisplayLargeImage(id) {
         document.getElementById('largeDisplay').src ='images/photo/large/'+id+'.png';
     }
 </script>



It first display the small image and onmouse over it show the large image in a different <div>
I created with the empty img tag.

The code to the function:
<img onmouseover="DisplayLargeImage(1)" alt="" src="images/photo/small/1.jpg" />

The code in the div:
<img id="largeDisplay" src="" />

Comment: You're welcome ! Do u mind kindly voting my answer up if you feel it was helpful ?